# What ASP.NET Web Config entries could limit certain file access by date and time?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, file-access

What entries in a web.config could allow certain files to become publicly accessible after a certain date and time?  Specifically, we have these files starting with AB__.jpg where the __ could be anything.  We put them in a folder on April 27th for example, but they shouldn't be accessible until April 30th at 11:59:59 PM.

I think the web.config in part works like Unix's FTP .htaccess file to define file security.

For example, this web.config entry allows directory browsing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: While thomas alluded to coding the mechanism, i am sure he is referring to an HttpModule, as david says. If you combine their answers you will have to solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom HTTP module to enforce this kind of security.  The module lets you see the incoming request and change its default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no configuration element in web.config that will let you control access to files or folders based on date or time. In order to achieve that, you would need to code that mechanism yourself.